# Problem creating endpoint with springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, endpoint, rest

**My task is to create endpoint, the logic is:**
User provides input --> **nip** (one of the variables in **Contractor.class**)
on the basis of that **nip**, I must return JSON, which will contain information about the product that is assigned to the contractor with the provided **nip**.
Example JSON should look like: *{**"name":** "product_name", **"quantity":** "0", **"address":** "storage_address"}*

I spent  lots of time on this problem, but still don't know what logic to implement.
It's over my newbie head;

**Product.class**:

```
public class Product extends AbstractEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private long quantity;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Assignment> assignments;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "product")
    private List<Place> places;
}
```

**Contractor.class**:

```
public class Contractor extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String contractorName;
    private int nip;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "contractor")
    private List<Assignment> assignments;
}
```

**Assignment.class**:

```
public class Assignment extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_product", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_contractor", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Contractor contractor;

}
```

**Storage.class**:

```
public class Storage extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "storage")
    private List<Place> places;
}
```

**Place.class**:

```
public class Place extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private Long shelfNumber;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_product", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Product product;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_storage", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Storage storage;

}
```

[image of ERD Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0512.png)

Comment: Should the endpoint return only one product, or can it return multiple products? What if product is in multiple places?

Comment: Endpoint should return every product that is assigned to that exact Contractor. What do you mean in multiple places?

Comment: The product has list of places. The storage also has list of places. Can you explain the relation between these?

Comment: I added Place.class and ERD Diagram of DB to the post.

Comment: Now I think that database structure is badly constructed, what if I delete the (Place table) and add deleted properties to (Assignment table) then connect (Storage table) to (Assignment table)? Wouldn't it be better?

Comment: But still the main problem is with the implementation of logic that returns json based on the nip.

Comment: Does the Place represents a shelf in a store? Meaby relation between Store and Place is in the wrong way (many to one or one to many).

Comment: Yes it does. I think you're right, these relations are wrongly implemented, I will change the database structure. But do you have any idea how to implement the logic to return multiple properties based just on one input property?

Comment: What logic do you need precisely? Also what is AbstractEntity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what logic do you need precisely. Also I am not sure if that code will fit to rest of your app. But maybe it will help.

The interface which will be returned by repository and by the rest controller:

```
public interface GetProductResponse {
    public String getName();
    public int getQuantity();
    public String getAddress();
}
```

The repository where you can write your query:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long>  {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, 
    value = (
"SELECT product.name AS name, product.quantity AS quantity, storage.address " + 
//be sure to name the result columns the variables in GetProductResponse (without the 'get')
"FROM contractor INNER JOIN assignment ON contractor.id = assignment.id_contractor " +
" INNER JOIN product ON product.id = assignment.id " +
" INNER JOIN place ON product.id = place.id_product " +
" INNER JOIN storage ON storage.id = place.id_storage " +
"WHERE contractor.nip = :nip_ "
    )
    public List<GetProductResponse> getProducts(@Param("nip_")String nip)
}
```

The rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getProductsByNip", method = { RequestMethod.POST})
    public List<GetProductResponsee> getProductsByNip(@RequestBody String nip) {
        return productRepository.getProducts(nip);
    }
}
```

The output will look like:

```
[
{"name": "product_name1", "quantity": "0", "address": "storage_address1"},
{"name": "product_name2", "quantity": "2", "address": "storage_address2"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the logic I was looking for! Can you help me a little bit more with the @Query you implemented? How the whole syntax should look like?

Comment: I added how the query could look like. Is that what you were looking for?